# How to delete multiple documents with specific Value in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, delete-file

I'm trying to delete multiple docs whith a specific String value in a Field from my collection.
But im doing something wrong I think.

```
onPressed: () async {
  Firestore.instance.collection('collection').getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
  for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.documents.where(('field') == 'specificValue'){
    ds.reference.delete();
    });
  });
}
```

Im currently trying to delete each Item with a loop after getting all documents, but im not able to delecte the specific Items. Because I'm getting an error under the "where" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `where`, you'll need to get the list of all the docs in that `collection`, then `where` to filter the `List` and delete the `filteredList`

```dart
  onPressed: () async {
    onPressed() async {
    Firestore.instance.collection('collection').getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> allDocs = snapshot.documents;
      List<DocumentSnapshot> filteredDocs =  allDocs.where(
              (document) => document.data['field'] == 'specificValue'
      ).toList();
      for (DocumentSnapshot ds in filteredDocs){
        ds.reference.updateData({
          'field': 'newValue'
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey, your function works great. But i noticed that it would be better to set the value "filed" to null for each document, instead of deleting them. Is it possible to do this with a updateData() function instead of the delete() function? When yes how can i only uopdate this one Field Value.

Comment: Ohh 'filed' is a type. it's meant to be 'field'